# How to change the passphrase for a private directory encrypted with ecryptfs

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I set up a `~/Private` directory, but now i want to change the passphrase i used. I moved all files out of that folder in order to start from scratch. So far i tried with:

```
~ $ cd /
/ $ ecryptfs-umount-private
/ $ ecryptfs-setup-private --force
```

I change to root because otherwise i would be unable to unmount. `ecryptfs-setup-private` then asks me to logout and login agan, but after doing that, i still cannot use my new passphrase to unmount and mount the directory again:

```
~ $ cd /
/ $ ecryptfs-umount-private 
/ $ ecryptfs-mount-private 
Enter your login passphrase:
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
ERROR: Your passphrase is incorrect
```

I think that the new passphrase was actually not adopted by ecryptfs, for some reason.

#### Note about duplication:

This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319561/change-the-passphrase-of-an-ecryptfs-directory), but i found the latter unclear and not helpful, because it is focusing about wrapping and unwrapping the passphrase, which is not related to this problem as far as i understand

Comment: Do you have a `wrapped-passphrase` file somewhere in your home folder? If you do, then you probably do want to unwrap/rewrap using a new passphrase. But, if everything's set up properly, then changing your user login passphrase normally should change the `wrapped-passphrase` file too since it should use your login passphrase to decrypt the eCryptFS folder.

Comment: I don't want to change my login passphrase. I want to change the passphrase used to encrypt/decrypt the Ecrypt folder

Comment: Are your login passphrase & ecryptfs passphrase the same now, or different? Does `ecryptfs-unwrap-pasphrase` work now? And you didn't answer if you even have a wrapped-passphrase file, do you?

Comment: My login passphrase is different from my ecryptfs passphrase. `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` works, it shows my new passphrase, but i cannot use the showed passphrase to unmount and remount. I think that the folder is styll encrypted with the old passphrase. I have a `~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` file

Comment: I might be getting confused between "login passphrase", "ecryptfs passphrase" (that unwraps the wrapped-passphrase file), and ecryptfs's "mount passphrase" (actual key to decrypt files). If you can still decrypt the files, then you just want to change the wrapped-passphrase file to use a new "ecryptfs passphrase", so you **do** want the rewrap passphrase tool. If you've changed the mount passphrase without re-encrypting the files with it, then you may have lost the files. If you want to erase everying & start over, why won't that work?

Comment: Yep, the terminology is definitely confusing here. What i want to do, is to change what you call the "mount passphrase". How can i change it? Running `ecryptfs-setup-private --force` seems to have actually kept the former mount passphrase. What should i erase?

Answer (score 0):

As said in [Change the passphrase of an ecryptfs directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319561/change-the-passphrase-of-an-ecryptfs-directory/568182#568182) :

> There is no way to change the passphrase on the fly as ecryptfs
>   encrypts each file with that passphrase individually and all files
>   need to be rewritten with the new passphrase.
>
> So all you can do is create a new directory, mount it with the new
>   passphrase and copy all the files over there.

Comment: This is exactly what i am trying to do with `ecryptfs-setup-private --force`